# Changing the datatype of specific dataframe columns - Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv

After reading my csv file using `read_csv()` in Pandas, I want to convert some of the column dataypes to `float64` for further processing, since they are currently represented as `object` dtype. Upon trying the attribute `dtype` in `read_csv`, I get the error. Following is the description:

```
import pandas as pd
file_ = pd.read_csv("/home/rahul/yearly_data_no_ecb.csv", dtype = {"DAX":"float64"})
```

Following is the full trace for the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-554c18573267> in <module>()
----> 1 file_ = pd.read_csv("/home/rahul/yearly_data_no_ecb.csv", dtype = {"DAX":"float64"})
  2 #file1 = pd.to_numeric(file_)
  3 file_.values
  4 file_.dtypes

/home/rahul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
703                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
704 
--> 705         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
706 
707     parser_f.__name__ = name

/home/rahul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
449 
450     try:
--> 451         data = parser.read(nrows)
452     finally:
453         parser.close()

/home/rahul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
1063                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
1064 
-> 1065         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
1066 
1067         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/home/rahul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
1826     def read(self, nrows=None):
1827         try:
-> 1828             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
1829         except StopIteration:
1830             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in     pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 11,535,309,570.00
```

How do I convert the dtype of the columns which have numeric data to float64?

If I only read in the csv, and check the dtype of the columns,

```
file_ = pd.read_csv("/home/rahul/yearly_data_no_ecb.csv")
file_.dtypes
```

I get this:

```
Year                                                     int64
City                                                    object
Return office city center                              float64
Average return logistics                               float64
Inverse return houses                                  float64
DAX                                                     object
MFI Interest Rate Germany                              float64
Inflation Rate                                         float64
GDP (EUR)                                               object
Size of City (km square)                                object
Total Population (Number)                               object
Population under 15 (Number)                            object
Population 15 to under 65 (Number)                      object
Population above 65 (Number)                            object
Total private households (Number)                       object
1 Person households (Number)                            object
2 Person households (Number)                            object
3 Person households (Number)                            object
4 Person households (Number)                            object
5 and more person households (Number)                   object
Total unemployment rate (Rate)                         float64
Total employment (Number)                               object
Available income per inhabitant (Eur)                   object
Total residential building (Number)                     object
Total Apartments (Number)                               object
Total new residential building approvals (Number)       object
Total new residential building completions (Number)     object
Total Migration                                         object
Returns                                                float64
Class                                                  float64
dtype: object
```

Basically, I want to convert the dtype (to `float64`) of columns `DAX`, `GDP` to `5 or more person households (Nuumber)` and `Total employment (Number)` to `Total Migration`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe you missed that you don't need to put quotes around specifying data-types while reading data from CSV, like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_ = pd.read_csv("/home/rahul/yearly_data_no_ecb.csv", dtype = {"DAX":np.float64})
```

Comment: If I specify it like this, I get a NameError:

`NameError: name 'float64' is not defined`

Comment: Updated the answer,  you need to use `numpy` for conversion to `float64`

Answer (score 2):

So if I want to change the datatype of columns c1 and c3 of the dataframe df to float64, here's what I'd do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([["1.2","dan","3"],["1.9","joe","5"]], columns = ["c1","c2","c3"])
print(df)
#    c1   c2 c3
# 0  1.2  dan  3
# 1  1.9  joe  5

print(df.dtypes)

#c1    object
#c2    object
#c3    object
dtype: object

df[['c1','c3']] = df[['c1','c3']].astype(np.float64)
print(df)
#    c1   c2   c3
# 0  1.2  dan  3.0
# 1  1.9  joe  5.0

print(df.dtypes)

# c1    float64
# c2     object
# c3    float64
# dtype: object
```

Comment: I did `file_[["DAX"]] = file_[["DAX"]].astype(np.float64)` and I get the exact same error as in the original question, namely; `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 11,535,309,570.00`.
This is very weird.

Comment: So you basically are trying to convert strings with commas into a float? Or maybe there's a problem with your csv file? Could you post the raw data file? That way I might be able to figure out why you still are having problems.